# How can I password protect my mlflow portal

Tags: python, authentication, nginx, centos7, mlflow

I have installed my mlflow on centos7 and hosting it at a port 5000.
I followed this article for reference: [Install MLFlow with postgres](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/setup-mlflow-in-production-d72aecde7fef)

I am looking to secure my mlflow UI with username and password. Any authentication method should be fine, however, Single Sign On is preferred.

I looked at this article: [Add Authentication to MLFlow](https://karimlahrichi.com/2020/03/13/add-authentication-to-mlflow/) It allows me to secure all the traffic going from port 80. After successful authentication I will be redirected to port 5000 where my MLFlow application is running. However, if I directly go to host:5000 my mlflow doesn't ask me for any authentication.
Please help me understand how I can enable mandatory authentication before you can reach the mlflow dashboard.

Comment: Disable the port 5000 to public access

Comment: if I disable that will it open up after a successful authentication on port 80?

Comment: Give a service endpoint to your application. The service endpoint is a like load balancer which access internal mlflow. So, directly hitting the internal pod can't happen as it's not exposed to external world. Look at kubernetes service endpoint

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SSO you can follow the authentication article that you posted and just use nginx to do the reverse proxy using SSO instead of your user/pass